# How RoundingMode works

Tags: java

I am bit confused about `RoundingMode.HALF_UP`, `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`, `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN`.

Can someone explain with an example please?

Recently I was going through some code I found like:

1. This will return 3.00 -- This is correct

   ```
   new BigDecimal(9.00).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
   ```
2. This will return 2.99 -- I couldn't understand this

   ```
   new BigDecimal(8.97).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
   ```
3. This will return 2.99 -- I couldn't understand this

   ```
   new BigDecimal(8.98).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
   ```
4. This will return 3.00 -- I couldn't understand this

   ```
   new BigDecimal(8.99).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
   ```

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: The Javadoc of [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) explains what each mode does and gives some examples.

Comment: I suggest you use `new BigDecimal("8.97")` so you know *exactly* what value you're dealing with to start with. And are you actually dividing by 3 rather than 2? The code you've got won't even compile due to use of `Bigdecimal` instead of `BigDecimal` - it would help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, but *what outputs did you expect*? What's confusing about the outputs you got?

Comment: Because `8.98 / 3.00` equals `2.993` which, when rounded to a scale of 2 using `HALF_UP`, becomes `2.99`. And `8.99 / 3.00` equals `2.997` which, when rounded the same as before, becomes `3.00`.

Comment: Your brackets don't match up in the sample code.

Comment: Note that you are using `new BigDecimal(double)` instead of `new BigDecimal(String)`, which means you might be introducing additional imprecision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the Javadoc for [divide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide(java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)), the `divide` operation returns a BigDecimal with the given scale (that is, decimal places). So we expect results with 2 decimal places, in cases 1/2/3/4.

Working out a few cases:

**case 2**

Note that `299*3=897`, hence `8.97/3` is exactly equal to `2.99`. The number `2.99` can be represented exactly (without loss of precision) using 2 decimal places. So the resulting bigDecimal value is 2.99. The code

```
System.out.println(8.97/3.);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(8.97).divide(new BigDecimal(3.), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

will output:

```
2.99
2.99
```

**case 3**

Since `8.98/3=2.993333333..`, the result can't be represented exactly using `scale=2`, and some rounding is needed. As explained in [RoundingMode.HALF_UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP), the number is rounded to the nearest number (with 2 decimal places). If we round down we get to `2.99`, and if we round up we get to `3.0`. The *nearest* rounded number is `2.99`, so `2.99333333..` is rounded down to `2.99`. The code

```
System.out.println(8.98/3.);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(8.98).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

outputs:

```
2.9933333333333336
2.99
```

**case 4**

Here `8.99/3=2.9966666..` and rounding is needed. Again, the nearest neighbours are: `2.99` (if we round down) and `3.0` (if we round up). The *nearest* number is `3.0`. Code

```
System.out.println(8.99/3.);
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(8.99).divide(new BigDecimal(3.00), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

will output

```
2.9966666666666666
3.00
```